# PhoneGap-Contacts not loading

Tags: android, cordova, contacts

i am in trouble for not getting all contacts. Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Contact Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.9.0.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery and jQuery Mobile -->
    <script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        document.addEventListener("deviceready", getContactList, false);

        function getContactList() { 
            var contactList = new ContactFindOptions(); 
            contactList.filter=""; 
            contactList.multiple=true;
            var fields = ["*"];  //"*" will return all contact fields
            navigator.contacts.find(fields,  getContactFields, contactList );
        }

        function getContactFields(contacts) {
            for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++)
            {
               alert(contacts.length);
               alert("Name:" + contacts[i].displayName + "\n"+
                         "Birthday:"+ contacts[i].birthday)

                for (var j=0; j<contacts[i].phoneNumbers.length; j++) {
                    alert("Type: " + contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j].type + "\n" + 
                        "Value: "  + contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j].value );
                } 
         }  

         alert("loaded");
    }
    </script>
```

Please help me where i am getting wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I have solve my problem. If any one need to list his phone number list then this code would be beneficial. Below is the source code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
<title></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css"> 
<!-- jQuery and jQuery Mobile -->
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script> 

<!-- for codova plugins --> 
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.9.0.js">  </script>     

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); 
    function onDeviceReady() {
        var options = new ContactFindOptions();
        options.filter = "";           
        options.multiple = true;       
        var fields = ["displayName", "phoneNumbers"];  
        navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);
    } 
    function onSuccess(contacts) {  
        for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) 
        {  
            if (contacts[i].phoneNumbers)
            {
                for (var j=0; j<contacts[i].phoneNumbers.length; j++) 
                {  
                    $('#contactlist').append(
                    '<li>' + 
                        '<a href="tel:'+ contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j].value +'">' +

                            '<h4>'+ contacts[i].displayName +'</h4>' + 
                            '<h4>'+ contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j].value +'</h4>' + 
                        '</a>' +
                    '</li>'); 
                } 
            }   
        }
        $('#contactlist').listview('refresh');
    }

    function onError(contactError) {
        alert('Error in getting Phone Contacts');
    }

 </script>

</head>
<body> 
  <div id="contactListPage" data-role="page" >

<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>Contacts</h1>
</div>

<div data-role="content">
     <ul id="contactlist" data-role="listview" data-filter="true"></ul>
</div>      

</div> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
// Cordova is ready
function onDeviceReady() {
    var options = new ContactFindOptions();
    options.filter = "";          // empty search string returns all contacts
    options.multiple = true;      // return multiple results
    var fields = ["displayName", "name"]; // Optional If you want particular fields then use filters 
    navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);
}

function onSuccess(contacts) {

    alert(contacts.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    }
}

function onError(contactError) {
    alert('Error in getting Phone Contacts');
}
```

Follow [Link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/phonegap_contacts_contacts.md.html#contacts.find)

Comment: @Imdad Sarkar- If you want contacts with birthday or contacts with some other fields, you can sort out that and display only those contacts using filter.

Comment: I have used that code previously. I can not figure out where i have made mistake.

Comment: How much contacts you are having in your phone and how much you are getting here by using this code ? (in alert)

Comment: my onSuccess(contacts) is not been calling.

Comment: I have only one contact in my phone, and i have noticed my onSuccess methode is not executing.

Comment: You added <plugin name="Contacts" value="org.apache.cordova.ContactManager" /> in your config ?

Comment: I have added that plugin and also permissions

Comment: Yes, i have tried your code, alert(contacts.length); in onSuccess method is not showing.

Comment: ok means your getContactList() is working but getContactFields() is not, as what your saying right?

Comment: My code is working like a charm giving mi all contacts of every phone. Something is wrong there in your code. As you are saying you have tried my code, you can follow link below my code. and try again? Which phone you are using is it android or IOS?

Comment: I am using symphony 125 android os 4.1.2

Comment: Thats what i gave you Imdad. Above code is what i am using in my all applications. You check your permissions and plugin again. And follow the link which i gave you.